# How can I delete n rows from a table using ctid?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with no primary key, just two columns with random varchar(100) values(cannot be sorted or used as a limit value). Is there a way to delete first n rows using ctid?
I imagine something like:

```
DELETE FROM my_table 
Where {my_table.ctid < '(0,10000)'}
```

Comment: I do not see how to delete x **first** row if the table is not sortable. If you want to use `ctid`, at least sort over this field (but you might now it changes each time your row is updated - [see doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/ddl-system-columns.html))

Comment: @Christophe not sortable in the way that content there is like: {"John", "Johnson"} and {"Mark", "Markson"}, you cannot sort through these values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE ctid in
 (SELECT ctid FROM my_table ORDER BY ctid LIMIT n);
```

Because you can't rely ctid's to mean any order you might as well delete random n rows

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE ctid in
 (SELECT ctid FROM my_table ORDER BY random() LIMIT n);
```

Comment: could you explain the "random n rows" phrase? When is row's ctid updated? Does it mean that if I need to repeatedly delete n rows (and only that, new values might be added in the end), that I might not delete it the way I want it?
Like delete first 1-10000, then 10001-20001 and so on

Comment: @ruslan agaev relational model is unordered. First n row is undefined unless you order explicitly on an attribute. ctid is an implementation detail, you can't rely on it for any meaningful ordering, for example it will change when a row is updated .

Comment: I think it works ok in my case, checked it out completely now